# PHP Isset Stack with another if condition?

Tags: php

having issues with some else if statements in php

```
ELSE if ($Departing != '' && $Departing2 !='')

ELSE if (isset($_GET['currenttimecheckbox'])){
```

I would like it so the second statement can also check `if  $Departing2 !=''` aswell

I am struggling to get these 2 to work together in the else if statement

Thanks

Comment: `isset($_GET['currenttimecheckbox']) && $Departing2 != ''`? And what has sql to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any condition in `elseif`

```
if($a != '' && $b != ''){
   // something happens
}elseif($a != '' && $b == ''){
   // something else happens    
}elseif($a == '' && b != ''){
   // something else than before happens
}else{
  // something happens when all previous conditions were false
}
```

Perhaps you could use the link below to get a basic understanding of logical operators in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following one?

```
if( isset($_GET['currenttimecheckbox']) && $Departing2 != '' )
{
    // your code here.
}
```